# Update main table based on last entry into a log table on id?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm not sure how to go about this. I have a relational database that information was just migrated too. Since the schema was changed from the old database, it took about 3 weeks to transfer the data properly. The old production database was still being used during that time. I have no transferred the remaining data, however this second migration just inserted new rows into the main table called tVehicleDeal and inserted the new values into the log table called tVehicleLog. My question is.. how can I update tVehicleDeal based on the last entry made into the tVehicleLog? My idea is that since the newest logs were inserted into the tVehicleLog table, then that should be the latest entry and I can use that entry to update tVehicleDeal. I know I can do something similar to this, but not sure how to get the last one for a deal.

```
UPDATE dbo.tVehicleDeal 
SET InternalLocationID = l.InternalLocationID
FROM dbo.tVehicleLog l
WHERE l.DealID = tVehicleDeal.DealID
```

Is there a way to do this properly? Any suggestions are helpful!

Comment: I added the sql-server tag because of the use of `dbo`.  If this isn't correct, please tag the question with the correct database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using `row_number()` and a `join`:

```
update vd 
    set InternalLocationID = l.InternalLocationID
from tVehicleDeal vd join
     (select vl.*,
             row_number() over (partition by l.DealId order by DATETIME desc) as seqnum
      from dbo.tVehicleLog l
     ) l
     on l.DealID = tVehicleDeal.DealID and seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This solution has definitely helped, however I was getting an error at DATETIME is not a valid column. So I put in one of my column names there, which was a DateTime column called DateChanged. This does work, however if there are two logs that have the same DateChanged (time is the same for them all as it was implemented later on) then it just updates from the first one.. and not the very last log for that particular deal. Any suggestions?

Comment: You didn't specify what the "latest entry" is in the question, that's why that is in all caps.  Whatever the column is that defines the "latest entry" is the one you should use.

Comment: Yes, I used the DateChanged column that I had, but I just changed it to the 'CommentID' and it now works properly. Thanks for the help!